# Posts paging [next] value eventually returns a empty array that should be populated

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Lets take a simple page like dominos. When I run a query like https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/posts?limit=200&access_token=[ANY OLD ACCESS TOKEN], it gives me the first page of post data. Then I go to the bottom and get next, after the 5th or 6th page of next values, I get an empty array. But when I go on dominos facebook page, they have more data past the last date of the last post on the last page that contained data.

I know that to access private data you need a specific access token, but this data is all public, and I know it is because I do not have to be logged in to see it.

To recreate this:

1. In browser https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/posts?limit=200
2. Go to bottom of page and get the next url
3. Continue doing #2 until you get to page #5 or #6 and you will get an empty data array preventing you from paging any further.

Any help or insights would be awesome.

[edit 04-20-2012]
Okay some more info:

I think this only relates to posts. When I do this:
https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/tagged?access_token=[anaccesstoken]&until=1262412000
I get back a page of results.

when I do this:
https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/posts?access_token=[anaccesstoken]&until=1262412000
I do not. But they are obviously posts there.

I checked the feed also: https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/feed?access_token=[anaccesstoken]&until=1262412000.

There are a bunch of user tagged there but no Domino's page posts.

Comment: I get `An access token is required to request this resource.` so perhaps your wrong about auth-ing

Comment: Just put any old access token, you can get one from here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: i do believe there is a limit to how far we can request back.  Let me find the doc, or note in blog.

Comment: I was looking around, but it seems like I hit this limit differently for different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls read the [article](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)

`the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the visibility checks is 5,000`

`1262412000` is the day in `Jan 2010`, 2 years ago. the most probable is that you have more than 5,000 posts in the past 2 years, so you can not fetch more than 5,000 posts.

I have also tried `https://graph.facebook.com/dominos/posts?limit=200&access_token=[anaccesstoken]&until=1322400000`, I could get the data. So `until parameter` works well.

Comment: Thanks. Facebook sent me this same email last night. I have another question that was not clean in that blog post, if I have an admin access token for a page, is it possible to get for than 5,000?

Comment: @chantheman, not sure, u can test it by yourself. I guess not. I thought FB make 2 db tables, one for the main site, another like temporary db only for fql, store latest ~5,000 posts, refresh by a certain time. this could reduce db pressure.

Comment: My hunch is you need the read_stream permission in the access token. I will check it out...